# What would be the possible outcome of this table in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a "Products" table that has two columns: product_code and product_name. The table is empty
and I want to execuite the following SQL statement.

```
INSERT INTO Products VALUES (100,’PIZZA’); 
INSERT INTO Products VALUES (150,’PASTA’); 
UPDATE Products SET product_name = ’PAPAYA’ 
WHERE product_code = 100;
CREATE PROFILE prof_sales LIMIT 
IDLE_TIME 15;               
UPDATE Products SET product_name = ’POTATO’ 
WHERE product_code = 150;
ROLLBACK;
```

1. Does the table remain empty because of the ROLLBACK?
2. The table Products will have two records. 100 PAPAYA and 150 PASTA.
3. Or the table Products will have two records. 100 PIZZA and 150 PASTA.
4. The table Products will have two records. 100 PAPAYA and 150 POTATO.
5. The PROFILE prof_sales will not be created.

These are the assumptions I am making and need an explanation for each assumption
as I am learning. Sorry I couldn't check the answers as my oracle 18c crashed for some reason.

It would be very kind if there is anyone who can help.

Comment: check your assumptions on livesql.oracle.com

Comment: I have tried many times in https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:1:7360981668154::NO:RP:: this link, but it provide error. please do favor me solve this issue and I want to know the theoretical logic for this assumption.

Comment: DDL statements such as `create profile` implicitly commit.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above.

The table will be empty but not because of the rollback.

All the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements will fail with the exception:

> ```sql
> ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated
> ```

Because you are using the character `’` for string literals when it should be `'`.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=6be82bb5b33c964bae6423c1937e73a9)*

---

If you fix the statements so they are all valid SQL statements then a DDL statement will implicitly `COMMIT` the prior statements; and then all the statements before the DDL statement will be committed and all the statements afterwards will `ROLLBACK`.

Since this looks like a homework/exam style exercise I'll leave working out exactly what happens to you.

Comment: I have made changes in code with correct ' sign and executed this with your provide fiddle link e.g :https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=29d1bf03438688b178abe1edc64b3202 as result it show up two item in product list. Please help me for find out  explain the theoretical parts of this question. It will very helpful for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ImranulHasan See the penultimate paragraph of the answer for the theory.